# 3-column table as DIV

Tags: html, css, browser, cross-browser, compatibility

Many people inquire about a div equivalent to a table, but unfortunately, I have not found an answer.

Basically, I want to achieve a layout like the following but without using tables.

[image: Setup]

This is the HTML and CSS code that works:

```
<table class="NV">
<tr><th colspan=3></th></tr>
<tr><td class="NVL">
<a href="page-1" rel="prev">
<div ID="NL"></div>See 1st photo album page</a>
</td><td>
<p>Page 2 of 19 (2/19)</p>
<span>
<a href="page-1">1</a>
<ins>2</ins>
<a href="page-3">3</a>
<a href="page-4">4</a>
<a href="page-5">5</a>
</span>
<br>
</td><td class="NVR">
<a href="page-3" rel="next">
<div ID="NR"></div>See 3rd photo album page</a>
</td></tr></table>

#NL,#NL2,#NR,#NR2{width:71px;height:70px}
#NL{background:-196px 0}
#NL2{background:-339px 0}
#NR{background:-267px 0}
#NR2{background:-410px 0}
.NV{width:100%;color:#000;background:#CCF;border:1px solid #FF0;text-align:center}
.NV INS{color:#FFF;background:#040;font-size:130%;padding:0.5em}
.NV INS,.NV A{margin:0.4em;padding:0.8em;display:inline-block;font:bold 100% arial}
.NV SPAN A{border:1px solid #000;background:#BDF;color:#000;font-size:100%}
.NV SPAN A:hover{background:#FFF;color:#000}
.NVR A,.NVR DIV{display:block;margin-left:auto;text-align:right}
.NVL A,.NVL DIV{display:block;margin-right:auto;text-align:left}
.NVL,.NVR{width:71px}
@media(max-width:500px){.NV INS,.NV A{margin:0.2em;padding:0.4em}}
```

Here's what I tried so far to make it a table-less layout:

```
<div class="NV">
<a ID="NL" href="page-1" rel="prev">See 1st photo album page</a>
<p>Page 2 of 9 (2/9)</p>
<span>
<a href="page-1">1</a>
<ins>2</ins>
<a href="page-3">3</a>
<a href="page-4">4</a>
<a href="page-5">5</a>
</span>
<a href="page-3" rel="next" ID="NR">See 3rd photo album page</a>
</div>

#NL,#NL2,#NR,#NR2{display:block;width:71px;height:70px}
#NL{background:-196px 0}#NL2{background:-339px 0}#NR{background:-267px 0}#NR2{background:-410px 0}
.NV{width:100%;color:#000;background:#CCF;border:1px solid #FF0;text-align:center}
.NV SPAN {vertical-align:middle}
.NV SPAN INS{color:#FFF;background:#040;font-size:130%;padding:0.5em}
.NV SPAN A{background:#BDF;color:#000}
.NV SPAN INS,.NV SPAN A{border:1px solid #000;margin:0.4em;padding:0.8em;display:block;width:20px;font:bold 100% arial}
@media(max-width:500px){
.NV INS,.NV A{margin:0.2em;padding:0.4em}
}
```

[image: bad layout]

If I wanted to fix this myself, I could declare everything as a block and use this in my CSS:

```
display:inline-block;
```

But according to w3c, mobile phones support CSS1 only, and inline-blocks and floats are bad things to use. Additionally, in older web browsers including IE6, inline-block doesn't work.

How can I fix this without resorting to using a table for layout?

and please ignore the mini black bar on the far right in the second image.

Comment: "But according to w3c, mobile phones support CSS1 only, and inline-blocks and floats are bad things to use. " **Say what? I think you may have misread that**

Answer (score 0):

I challenge you to find anyone actually running a browser like IE6 anymore -- remember, to even make that possible you'd have to be running XP with updates off.  Sure, they're out there, but by now, those people running them know there's limitations.

This would be a very acceptable answer for my team, and we're quite strict about w3 compliance -- our clients around the world demand it.  I encourage you to run it in various browsers and see which ones can't handle it.  [Here's a great site](http://caniuse.com/#feat=inline-block) that proves over 97% of browsers (including Mobile Phones, which also force auto update) can support it.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">  
    <div class="arrow"><img src="../path/to/arrow.jpg"></div>
    <div class="number"><a href="#">1</a></div>
    <div class="number"><a href="#">2</a></div>
    <div class="number"><a href="#">3</a></div>
    <div class="number"><a href="#">4</a></div>
    <div class="number"><a href="#">5</a></div>
    <div class="number"><a href="#">6</a></div>
    <div class="arrow"><img src="../path/to/arrow.jpg"></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
     width: 50%;
}
.number, .arrow {
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: center;

}
.number a:link, .arrow a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[Here's the fiddle to try yourself.](https://jsfiddle.net/e3f5j4j7/)

Since we're getting absolutely crazy about HTML and all, it's better to use a glyph than an image for your arrows.  Just sayin'......

Comment: It would be a good answer, but I want to include the graphic arrows as well.

Comment: So put them in!  That's trivial, dude.

Comment: But it isn't that easy because they come from an image sprite and when I try doing things the short way, I attempt to turn my anchor tags for the arrows into images via display:block. They appear, but the rest of the content is shifted down which is what I do not want.

Comment: You're overthinking it.  Put up a fiddle with your sprite and we'll show you how to clean it up.  Without that, we're stuck.